# restrict the print of output from function

Tags: r

My question is how to restrict or stop the output of functions.

For example, the `rstan::sampling()` launches the following output: How to restrict such print.

```
Chain 1: Iteration:    1 / 10000 [  0%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 1000 / 10000 [ 10%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 2000 / 10000 [ 20%]  (Warmup)
Chain 1: Iteration: 2001 / 10000 [ 20%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 3000 / 10000 [ 30%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 4000 / 10000 [ 40%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 5000 / 10000 [ 50%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 6000 / 10000 [ 60%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 7000 / 10000 [ 70%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 8000 / 10000 [ 80%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 9000 / 10000 [ 90%]  (Sampling)
Chain 1: Iteration: 10000 / 10000 [100%]  (Sampling)
```

Comment: ?suppressMessages()

Answer (score 1):

maybe use verbose = FALSE

Se here: https://github.com/stan-dev/rstan/wiki/RStan-Getting-Started (under More help)